# knitr html to Word docx using pandoc

Tags: r, knitr, pandoc

I have been saving some example R markdown html output to Word using `pandoc`. I actually only do this so I can add some page breaks for easier printing:

```
system("pandoc -s Exercise1.html -o Exercise1.docx")
```

Although the output is acceptable I was wondering if there is a way to keep the original syntax highlighting of the R chunks (just as they are in the original knit HTML document)?

Also, I seem to be loosing all images in the conversion process and have to stick them into Word by hand. Is that normal?

Comment: Try open html file in Word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [rmarkdown package](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) (baked into RStudio Version 0.98.682, [the current preview release](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/download/preview)) it's very simple to convert Rmd to docx, and code highlighting is included in the docx file.

You just need to include this at the top of your markdown text:

```
---
title: "Untitled" # obviously you can change this
output: word_document # specifies docx output
---
```

However, it seems that page breaks are still not supported in this conversion.

Answer (score 3):

Why not convert the markdown directly to Word format?

Anyway, Pandoc does not support syntax highlighting in Word: "[Currently, the only output formats that uses this information are HTML and LaTeX.](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#fenced-code-blocks)"

About the images: the Word file would definitely include those if you'd convert the markdown to Word directly. I am not sure about the HTML source, but I suppose you might have a path issue.

Comment: When I use markdown the complete knitr strings are displayed. But perhaps I get it to work with a PDF in between... I'll try it out now.